# Check If Two Lists Are Equal and Maintain Order

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to match two list that have same value, so I used the following that worked fine:

```
bool equal = false;
equal = aLst1.SequenceEqual(aLst2);
```

**Sample Data**:

```
aLst1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 } 
aLst2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }

aLst1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 } 
aLst2 = { 2, 3, 1, 4 }
```

So for above list, it returns me true as they have similar values regardless their order. In the sample data section - Second one, what I prefer is to check the order as well. If order doesn't match, it should return false.

```
aLst1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 } 
aLst2 = { 2, 3, 1, 4 }
```

I was thinking to use `Order By` but that wouldn't solve it. Any other method that could be used in this scenario?

Comment: To me the SequenceEqual returns false on your second example data.

Comment: When I tested it, I could not reach the result you said. Working right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a generic method that solves the problem:

```
    static bool ListsHaveSameElements<T>(IEnumerable<T> list1, IEnumerable<T> list2)
    {
        return list1.Count() == list2.Count() &&
               list1.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(list2.OrderBy(x => x));
    }
```

I added the `Count()` check for efficiency reasons.